# Error Message while executing command in Arbiter for log rotation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

While running the command in the shell `db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )` of arbiter it showing an error message as not authorized to run this command but in primary and secondary of `replicaset` its working. So what's the solution for this version is 3.4.3.

Comment: what is your O.S environment?

Answer (score 0):

As per **MongoDB BOL** [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/rotate-log-files/) Rotate the log file by issuing the [logRotate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/logRotate/#dbcmd.logRotate) command from the admin database in a `mongo shell`:

```
db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

You must issue the logRotate command against the [admin database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-admin-database) in the form:

```
{ logRotate: 1 }
```

Note : Your [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance needs to be running with the `--logpath [file]` option.

Comment: Its centos 7 but its not working arbiter  it need authentication but while giving authentication which we are using for primary and seconadry in this replica set its not working for arbiter so whats the solution

Comment: @ashk,Have you checked your  "logpath" or "systemLog.path" settings configuration.

Comment: log path is same as primary and secondary but while  using use admin and run this command db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) its shownig not authorized to execute this command authentication required